# Connection between derived sets and derived subgroups, if any

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, soft-question

In topology, we may consider a topological space $X$. A subset $S$ of $X$ has its "derived set" $S'$, the set of all limit points of $S$. On the other hand, in algebra, we have a group $G$, and the derived subgroup $G' = [G, G]$ is the set of all finite products of commutators of $G$.

Moreover, we sometimes consider the chains of derived sets
 $$A' \supset A'' \supset A''' \supset \cdots $$
and derived subgroups
$$G' \supset G'' \supset G''' \supset \cdots $$
That is about all I know that is common between the two structures. Is there a deeper notion of "derived" going on here, between topological spaces and groups, and perhaps other structures, or is it just two superficially similar operations that happen to share the same name?

Comment: No, there are some pretty cool relationships between algebraic structures and topological structures, but this ain't it

Comment: If you go further you'll see that for both, the cases where $X' = X$ are called *perfect* (perfect group, perfect space). But I think it's just that both operations take a thing and return a smaller thing, and we want to see when taking the smaller thing actually stops because it leads to interesting situations we understand a bit better - to my knowledge there's nothing deeper here

Comment: That's disappointing, but thanks for the answers. If anyone wants to give a full answer discussing similarities between algebraic and topological structures - even if only tangentially related to the question - I'm sure it'd be interesting.